# Custom Actionbar icon compatible with other themes the user may choose

Tags: android, android-icons

When creating custom ActionBar icons what happens if the user changes their theme to something  that makes your icon unreadable? Do they have this kind of power?

**Example:** So say I make an icon for my ActionBar in Holo Dark, so that the icon will be a lighter shade of white. What if the user changes their theme to Holo Light (or can they in my app?), forcing my icon to not be readable because it is also close to the same color as its background? I'm just concerned that if I create a custom app it will not look proper to only certain people.

I have been trying to find something about this but my searches and Google's Iconography pages didn't really give me a clear answer.

Comment: BTW if anyone ever has this problem check `android-sdk-root/platforms/android-X/data/res/drawable-hdpi` first to make sure that you're icon isn't there... mine isn't but I thought I'd just add that.

Answer (score 0):

Android allows setting a themes to application/activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`, and you can change theme theme dynamically. If a user change their system themes,  it don't affect you application. If you want to change your application/activity themes, you should call `setTheme()` before `setContentView()` in `Activity.onCreate()`